Runscript details used by TexWorks
After using MikTeX on Windows for many years, and facing constant issues, I decided to install TeXlive on windows. It worked well with the exception now and then I get the error shown on the image below; I could not find where the runscript is located to check the line.I suspect it might have to do with either perl or python paths (I am not sure what the script uses). Can anyone help?
I get this compiling LuaLaTeX via the TeXworks, interface. The pdf gets produced and the error comes right at the end of the compilation, with TeXworks closing.


Did you do install a full or a limited version of TeXLive?

@Mico I dd a full install
